# Why are `?` and `!` not allowed in variable names while they are allowed in method names?

Tags: ruby

I often want to do something like the following to store a boolean flag in a variable:

```
populated? = City.inhabitants.any?
```

but this raises an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '='
```

Is this due to there being some ambiguity in the language or is it simply not implemented?

Comment: It is a duplicate with respect to `?`, but not with respect to `!`.

Comment: You need to make your question clear. The title is clear, but the text is not. How is your code and the error relevant to the question that you raise in the title?